# Eddy current loss formula

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, inductor, magnetics

I have a question about eddy's current loss formula.

I find a [website](https://www.electricalvolt.com/2021/07/what-is-eddy-current-loss-definition-and-expression/) talking about the eddy current formula.

[image]

[image]

and I also read the one paper, in this [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4277910), there is a formula called eddy current, but it is not the same as the website, so I would like to know which one is correct.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The formulas are different because they assume different boundary conditions.

The first deals with loss in a sheet (that is, a rectangular conductor much wider than it is thick) where the magnetic flux component is parallel to the sheet length. These conditions represent the magnetizing flux of a transformer in a laminated magnetic core generating induced currents in the sheets.

The second formula deals with a rectangular conductor with width and thickness in the same order of magnitude in which the field reaches one of these dimensions perpendicularly. These conditions represent the stray flux of a transformer generating induced currents in the conductors of the windings.